# How to interpolate property within double quotes in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I want to set background of a div using angular property for this I have used this code but not working. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="overlay" style="background: url({{ main_banner.banner_image }} ) no-repeat"></div>
```

Comment: which is the result? you are going well, i think you have a css problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle directive. I assume you can do something like this in your component:

```
var yourStyle = {
   'background' : 'url(\'Your url\') no-repeat'
};
```

And view:

<`div class="overlay" [ngStyle]="yourStyle"></div`>